# Ansible: How to get the stack output in proper format

Tags: ansible

Below is my ansible playbook for creating the rds.

```
- name: provision stack
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  # Launch the cloudformation-example.yml template.  Register the output.

  tasks:
  - name: launch ansible cloudformation example
    cloudformation: >
      stack_name="ansible-cloudformation" state=present
      region=us-east-1 disable_rollback=true
      template=files/simple-rds.yml
    args:
      template_parameters:
        vpcid: vpc-0123456
        application: abc
        appSubnetCidr1: 201.0.0.0/20
        appSubnetCidr2: 201.0.0.0/22
        dbCreateNewParamsGroup: true
        dbInstanceType: db.t2.micro
        dbName: testdb
        dbSubnetId1: subnet-87654321
        dbSubnetId2: subnet-12345678
        dbUsername: master_user
        environment: development
        product: ""
        dbPassword: ""
        techContact: ""
    register: stack
  - name: show stack events
    debug: msg="My stack events are {{stack.events}}"
```

When I run the playbook I am getting stack events like this. It's coming in distorted form :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "My stack outputs are [u'StackEvent AWS::CloudFormation::Stack dev-beanstalk-ansible UPDATE_COMPLETE', u'StackEvent AWS::CloudFormation::Stack BeanstalkTemplateStack UPDATE_COMPLETE', u'StackEvent AWS::CloudFormation::Stack BeanstalkTemplateStack UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'...
```

**How to get the output in proper format** Like I mentioned below. I have tried {{ stack.stack_resources }}, {{ stack.stack_outputs }} as well. All having the same issue.

```
events": [
        "StackEvent AWS::CloudFormation::Stack dev-beanstalk-ansible UPDATE_COMPLETE",
        "StackEvent AWS::CloudFormation::Stack BeanstalkTemplateStack UPDATE_COMPLETE",
        "StackEvent AWS::CloudFormation::Stack BeanstalkTemplateStack UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS",
```

Comment: What's distorted here? You requested to print a list and you got a list in Python notation. What is "*proper format*"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the built-in [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data)?

You could try

```
- name: debug events
  debug: msg="My stack events are {{stack.events | to_nice_json }}"
```

Comment: It is still showing in this form: ` "msg": "My stack outputs are {\n    \"dbHost\": \"os-development-rds.cnssssds.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com\", \n    \"dbPort\": \"3306\", \n    \"dbSubnetGroup\": \"os-development-rds-subnet\", \n    \"sgRDS\": \"sg-04680sdds1cc\"\n}" `